# System.IO.FIleNotFoundException with System.IO.Ports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I want to use the SerialPort framework of .NET and just learning the ropes of coding in a Windows Environment in C#. I am not new to coding, but I have still challenges understanding the Windows environment.

I get the following error when trying to start the program:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=ConnectionRepository.Serial
  StackTrace:
   at ConnectionRepository.Serial.SerialConnection.GetSerialPortNames() in C:\Users\KG-OFFICE\source\repos\DeepSky\ConnectionRepository.Serial\SerialConnection.cs:line 17
   at DeepSky.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\KG-OFFICE\source\repos\DeepSky\DeepSky\Form1.cs:line 25
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The class using SerialPort I wrote looks like this:

```
using ConnectionRepository.Interface;
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConnectionRepository.Serial
{
    public class SerialConnection : IConnectionRepository
    {

        static SerialPort _serialPort;

        public static string[] GetSerialPortNames()
        {
            string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            return portNames;
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OpenConnection()
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

The main program:

```
namespace DeepSky
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IConnectionRepository serialConnection = new SerialConnection();
            string[] portNames = SerialConnection.GetSerialPortNames();
            cBoxComPort.Items.AddRange(portNames);
        }
    }
}
```

when I added `System.IO.Ports` it first did not recognize it and threw an error message. Then I read, I need to add it via NuGet, which I did and the error disappeared. But when building the solution, I get this error above.

I also added the references accordingly, but can't get it to run. Can you help me out?

Comment: This not a build error, this is a runtime error. You can see it in the stack trace. (Form_Load()) I am trying to reproduce.

Comment: It works on my machine. How did you add the NuGet package? You should right click the windows forms project and select Manage NuGet Packages and add it from there. (Which I think you did)

Comment: Is the SerialConnection  class in another assembly (another class library project?) in that case check you framework versions for both the forms app and the class library. Let them match.

Comment: Hi Oguz, thanks for the hint... the Package i downloaded was not persistent after downloading and disappeared again. I checked by accident the NuGet Library and it was not downloaded (anymore). Now it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem seems to be at `_serialPort.Open()`: you are trying to open a connection without having yet defined any port...
Try passing any of the ports you have discovered and saved to `portNames`. You also might want to set it a `BaudRate = 9600` for example. In general, the useful params to set would be:

```
port = new SerialPort()
{
   PortName = "COM3",
   BaudRate = 9600,
   Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None,
   DataBits = 8,
   StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One,
   //Handshake=Handshake.RequestToSend,
   ReadTimeout = 500, // waits for text to come over the COM
   WriteTimeout = 500,
};
```